# Mongo: How do I group documents based on one of two fields?

Tags: mongodb, set

If I have documents that look like:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    val1: x,
    val2: aa
},
{
    _id: 2,
    val1: y,
    val2: bb
},
{
    _id: 3,
    val1: x,
    val2: cc
},
{
    _id: 4,
    val1: z,
    val2: bb
}
```

Is it possible to group them in MongoDB so that docs 1 and 3 are paired and docs 2 and 4 are paired?

In essence, I'm looking to group docs if their val1 OR val2 are the same. Also, there will NOT be the possibility of docs being able to be in two different groups. Meaning, I should be able to partition the set of docs. Is the possible in Mongo?

Ultimately, I want to partition my set of documents based on the aforementioned criteria and then count the size of each subset.

I've tried attacking this problem by grouping on the val1 field and using $addToSet to created an array of val2's. But then I'm stuck because I don't know of a way in Mongo to merge arrays that contain at least one common element. If I did, I could use that list of arrays and aggregate again using $in.

Please let me know if I can clarify my question in any way!

Comment: You seem to be definately abstracting from your real problem here and that seems to dangerously veer towards explainations that are not what you want. The problem space presented is determining which field to use as the grouping key. ie That `val2` is the duplicated value from two documents. You need to think *"how would you know that"* without already parsing through all documents and finding the combinations of two or more and where they reside? You cannot. I suspect your actual problem has a different approach, if you only explained that instead.